# Embed live video from two of my website users' webcams

Tags: video, video-streaming, html5-video, webrtc, live-streaming

As per the title, I want to stream video from two of my website visitors' webcams (with their permission, of course) to my website.

I am trying to figure out how to do this, but really don't know where to start. I've done research but everything I've found refers to using Flash, which I think is outdated? Is this an ideal application for WebRTC?

Any suggestions for how one might go about this would be appreciated. I'm very new to this.

Thank you

Comment: In case it is relevant, I am most familiar with Rails and Javascript.

Comment: if you want to exchange video streams between the two users, you would find a lot of WebRTC examples for that, if you want to send stream to server( from one user or n users, makes little difference in implementation), you could try looking into MCU / SFU like Licode, Kurento, Janus Gateway...

Comment: I want to send both streams to my website so other website visitors can watch them.

Answer (score 0):

theoretically, you do not need to send the streams to server, you could just link all the viewers to the broadcasters directly using WebRTC. But, it would drain the bandwidth of the broadcaster if not just crash the browser.

Practically speaking, you could do all you want with a simple SFU( Selective Forwarding Unit) setup on your server. Like mentioned in the comments, you can take a look at this [kurento example](http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.org/en/stable/tutorials/node/tutorial-one2many.html) for one-to-many broadcasting. Personally I prefer [Licode](https://github.com/ging/licode), tend to feel that their API is easier to use.